# Configuring react-toolbox sass variables with toolbox-loader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, sass, react-toolbox

I want to change the default value of $appbar-height variable.

I create toolbox-theme.scss file with

```
$appbar-height: 3 * $unit !default;
```

But I get a lot of errors:

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader?sourceMap&modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!./~/sass-loader?sourceMap!./~/toolbox-loader!./~/react-toolbox/lib/app/style.scss
Module build failed: 
  top: 0;
                   ^
      Undefined variable: "$unit".
      in /home/jules/projects/tourbnb-frontend/node_modules/react-toolbox/lib/app/style.scss (line 3, column 21)
 @ ./~/react-toolbox/lib/app/style.scss 4:14-230 13:2-17:4 14:20-236

ERROR in ./~/css-loader?sourceMap&modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!./~/sass-loader?sourceMap!./~/toolbox-loader!./src/styles/styles.scss
Module build failed: 
undefined
                   ^
      Undefined variable: "$unit".
      in /home/jules/projects/tourbnb-frontend/src/styles/styles.scss (line 3, column 21)
 @ ./src/styles/styles.scss 4:14-261 13:2-17:4 14:20-267

ERROR in ./~/css-loader?sourceMap&modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!./~/sass-loader?sourceMap!./~/toolbox-loader!./src/components/header/style.scss
Module build failed: 
@import "~react-toolbox/lib/button/config";
                   ^
      Undefined variable: "$unit".
      in /home/jules/projects/tourbnb-frontend/src/components/header/style.scss (line 3, column 21)
 @ ./src/components/header/style.scss 4:14-269 13:2-17:4 14:20-275

ERROR in ./~/css-loader?sourceMap&modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!./~/sass-loader?sourceMap!./~/toolbox-loader!./~/react-toolbox/lib/button/style.scss
Module build failed: 
@import "./config";
                   ^
      Undefined variable: "$unit".
      in /home/jules/projects/tourbnb-frontend/node_modules/react-toolbox/lib/button/style.scss (line 3, column 21)
 @ ./~/react-toolbox/lib/button/style.scss 4:14-230 13:2-17:4 14:20-236

ERROR in ./~/css-loader?sourceMap&modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!./~/sass-loader?sourceMap!./~/toolbox-loader!./~/react-toolbox/lib/app_bar/style.scss
Module build failed: 

                   ^
      Undefined variable: "$unit".
      in /home/jules/projects/tourbnb-frontend/node_modules/react-toolbox/lib/app_bar/style.scss (line 3, column 21)
 @ ./~/react-toolbox/lib/app_bar/style.scss 4:14-230 13:2-17:4 14:20-236

ERROR in ./~/css-loader?sourceMap&modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!./~/sass-loader?sourceMap!./~/toolbox-loader!./~/react-toolbox/lib/ripple/style.scss
Module build failed: 

                   ^
      Undefined variable: "$unit".
      in /home/jules/projects/tourbnb-frontend/node_modules/react-toolbox/lib/ripple/style.scss (line 3, column 21)
 @ ./~/react-toolbox/lib/ripple/style.scss 4:14-230 13:2-17:4 14:20-236
```

If I change my config file to `$color-primary-dark: $palette-blue-700 !default;` it works all right and changes the color. How is `$unit` different from `$palette-blue-700`?

My webpack loader for styles:

```
{
    test: /(\.css|\.scss)$/,
    loader: 'style!css?sourceMap&modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!sass?sourceMap!toolbox'
}
```

Comment: And where is `$unit` defined?  You can't use it if it hasn't been defined yet.

Comment: it's defined [here](https://github.com/react-toolbox/react-toolbox/blob/dev/components/_globals.scss) Why I can reference `$palette-blue-700` that is defined [here](https://github.com/react-toolbox/react-toolbox/blob/dev/components/_colors.scss) but not `$unit`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

toolbox-loader only imports the `_colors.scss` file (see [first code line](https://github.com/react-toolbox/toolbox-loader/blob/master/index.js))

you have to import the `_globals.scss` file manually (or fork toolbox-loader).

Comment: Yes, `@import "~react-toolbox/lib/_globals";` worked, thanks. However I wasn't able to overwrite `$appbar-height` :-/

Comment: Did you try without `!default`? ;)

Comment: Yes, it still doesn't work. I put `!deafult` there because that's how they do it in the [sample app](https://github.com/react-toolbox/react-toolbox-example/blob/master/app/toolbox-theme.scss)

Comment: As I see [here](https://github.com/react-toolbox/react-toolbox/blob/dev/components/app_bar/_config.scss#L4) the height isn't ment to be overriden (missing !default flag). Same advice here - fork, test & send a pull request (I'm not a maintainer of the project, nor a user ;) )

Comment: I just created a pull request [#301](https://github.com/react-toolbox/react-toolbox/pull/301) hope you can use this soon ;)